# Django form list field or json field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a model called participants as below

```
class participants(models.Model):
     username= models.CharField(max_length =50)
     votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
     voted_by = ?
```

Votes is the total number of votes given by users and single user can vote multiple times. If the user have voted then the user should wait 1 hour to vote again. Now i am wondering, how can i store users id in a way that it would be easier to know who voted how many times and the recent date and time the user have voted.

Can someone suggest me or refer some examples that i can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another model (eg. VotesHistory)...

```
class VotesHistory(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Vote Log"
        verbose_name_plural = "Vote Logs"

    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Time")
    uid = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Voter's UserID")
    pid = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Voted UserID")
```

Now, when user 1 will vote user 2, you can create an entry such as,

```
VotesHistory(uid=user1.id, pid=user2.id).save()
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem is generally solved by using a `ForeignKey` reference.

```
# class name should begin with a capital letter and should be singular for a model
class Participant(models.Model):
     username = models.CharField(max_length =50)


class Vote(models.Model)
    vote_to = models.ForeignKey(Participant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='vote_to')
    voted_by = models.ForeignKey(Participant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='voted_by')
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Each *vote* by a *participant* would be a row in the `Votes` table or an object of type `Vote`.
Something like,

```
vote = Vote(vote_to=some_participant_object,
            voted_by=someother_participant_object)
vote.save()
```

`auto_now=True` means the value will be added when the object gets created so you don't have to handle when the vote was cast.

You can then query the number of votes cast by a particular participant using the ORM.

A basic filter query should be enough. Get all the votes by a particular participant.
Something like,

```
# just as an idea here, the next lines might not be perfect
votes = Vote.objects.filter(voted_by__id=some_participant_id)
# or
votes = Vote.objects.filter(voted_by=some_participant_object)
# check the timestamp of the last vote and build logic accordingly
```

This way it'll be easier to write ORM queries to count the number of votes a particular participant has or the number of votes a particular participant has cast.